# Count number of line in txt file when new line is inside data

Tags: regex, shell, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have one txt file which has below data

```
Name    mobile  url message text
test11  1234567890  www.google.com  "Data Test New
Date:27/02/2020
Items: 1
Total: 3
Regards
ABC DATa
Ph:091 : 123456789"
test12  1234567891  www.google.com  "Data Test New one
Date:17/02/2020
Items: 26
Total: 5
Regards
user test
Ph:091 : 433333333"
```

Now you can see my last column data has new line character. so when I use below command

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file.txt
```

it is giving my length is 15 but actually line length is 3 . Please suggest command for the same

Edited Part:
As per the answer given the below script is not working if there's no newline at the end of input file

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\n/, " ", RT); ORS=RT} END{print NR "\n"}' test.txt
```

Also my file may have 3-4 Million of records . So converting file to unix format will take time and that is not my preference.
So Please suggest some optimum solution which should work in both case

```
head 5.csv | cat -A  
Above command is giving me the output
```

Name    mobile  url message text^M$

Comment: You cannot have a line with a newline character inside it: you automatically create a new line (which is the whole idea).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Comment: So you want to known number of newline characters outside `""`?

Comment: @Daweo I want to count number of line inside this file and for given data it should give 3

Comment: @user13000875, we understand you want to count number of lines but our question is what is the Logic of counting a multiple(lines separated by new lines) lines as 1 line, kindly do make it clear in your question.

Comment: Are your columns separated by tabs?

Comment: What you're calling a line isn't a line in POSIX terms because a line is a string that ends in a newline and therefore cannot contain a newline. That's what's confusing everyone. What you should be calling it instead is a record and then you can define what you mean by a record, e.g. a string of text ending in a newline that can contain newlines within quoted fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` you can do this using a custom `RS`:

```sh
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/(\r?\n){2,}/, "\n"); n+=gsub(/\n/, "&")}
END {print n}' <(sed '$s/$//' file)

15001
```

Here:

- `-v RS='"[^"]*"'`: Uses this regex as input record separator.  Which matches a double quoted string
- `n+=gsub(/\n/, "&")`: Dummy replace `\n` with itself and counts `\n` in variable `n`
- `END {print n}`: Prints `n` in the end
- `sed '$s/$//' file`: For last line adds a newline (in case it is missing)

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/ZG2riw)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225762/discussion-on-answer-by-anubhava-count-number-of-line-in-txt-file-when-new-line).

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, assuming last line always ends with a newline character

```sh
$ perl -0777 -nE 'say s/"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\n//g' ip.txt
3
```

- `-0777` to slurp entire input file as a single string, so this isn't suitable if the input file is very large
- the `s` command returns number of substitutions made, which is used here to get the count of newlines
- `"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)` will cause newlines within double quotes to be ignored

You can use the below command if you want to count the last line even if it doesn't end with newline character.

```sh
perl -0777 -nE 'say scalar split /"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\n/' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65035168/1331399) but with GNU sed:

```
<infile sed '/"/ { :a; N; /"$/!ba; s/\n/ /g; }' | wc -l
```

Output:

```
3
```