# replace new line character between double quotes with \n in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

Data sample input:

```
Name    mobile  url message text
test11  1234567890  www.google.com  "Data Test New
Date:27/02/2020
sample1: 1bags
sample2: 20bags
Regards
The test user user user Sangha
Ph:091 : 123456789"
test12  1234567891   www.google.com  hello
```

My output should be

```
Name    mobile  url message text
test11  1234567890  www.google.com  "Data Test New\nDate:27/02/2020\nsample1: 1bags\nsample2: 20bags\nRegards\nThe test user user user Sangha\nPh:091 : 123456789"
test12  1234567891  www.google.com  hello
```

I have used the below command but it's not working

```
awk '!/"$/{sub(/$/,"\\n");printf "%s",$0;next}1' file
```

I have used several other commands as well, but none of them are working in my case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of line in txt file when new line is inside data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035029/count-number-of-line-in-txt-file-when-new-line-is-inside-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`, you may do this:

```sh
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\r?\n/, "\\n", RT); ORS=RT} 1' file

Name    mobile  url message text
test11  1234567890  www.google.com  "Data Test New\nDate:27/02/2020\nItems: 1\nTotal: 3\nRegards\nABC DATa\nPh:091 : 123456789"
test12  1234567891   www.google.com  hello
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/sCQJvB)

Comment: after using your script I am getting below output
Name    mobile  url message text
 Ph:091 : 123456789"user Sanghagle.com "APMC BANGALORE ARRIVALS
test12 1234567891  www.google.com  hello

Comment: it's working there then why it's not working from my terminal.

Comment: gawk is already installed in my system . When I run command sudo apt-get install gawk 
then I am getting gawk is already the newest version

Comment: it's giving GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Comment: Do `cat -A file` to check if input has any DOS line ending i.e. `^M` characters.

Comment: Yes it has ^M. But my user can  upload file from any OS. only my server will be ubuntu

Comment: Then you can use: `awk -v RS='("[^"]*")' '{gsub(/\r?\n/, "\\n", RT); ORS=RT} 1' file`

Comment: it's works perfectly . Thank you so much .You are such a helpful person